# Mongo schema Plugins with prisma ORM

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

Hey I want schema plugins for mongodb how can I do that using prisma ORM ?
Also any way for giving mixed type for schema property ?

I have googled for the same but no reference to be found

Example: I want soft delete, pre and post plugin hooks etc...